# Linear span of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

$\newcommand{\span}{\operatorname{span}}$Given $X,Y$, subsets of a vector space $V$ of finite dimension. Is it true that $\span(X \cap Y)=\span(X)+\span(Y)$ and $\span(X \cup Y)=\span(X) \cup \span(Y)$ ?

Comment: I think this is false, but I could not argue well. I don't know.

Comment: For the first one, take any $X$, $Y$ so that $X\cap Y  = \{0\}$.

Comment: @NicholasStull Thanks, that would be a counterexample. And the second?

Comment: Why do you write X{\cap}Y instead of X\cap Y?  It makes you see $X{\cap}Y$ instead of $X\cap Y$. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm sorry, i just start to learn the codes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first is false as is in the comments, just take any $X,Y$ with zero intersection.

second is false as well -- left side is a subspace, the right - not necessarily, e.g. let $X = \{\vec{x}\},Y = \{\vec{y}\}$ with $\vec{x}, \vec{y}$ not collinear...

Comment: The only time when the union of two subspaces *is* a subspace, is when one is a subset of the other.

Answer (score 5):

Both are false, and counterexamples of comments you can see, what we do is true is that $span(X{\cup}Y)=span(X)+span(Y)$.